# How to use the enumerate function on a txt file?

Tags: python

I am trying to read the Hi.txt file that I previously created on the console but instead of just getting the values from it I'm trying to add the index value next to it using the enumerate function. (Let's assume that the text file has 3 elements in it).

```
with open('Hi.txt','r') as hello:
    x = hello.read()
    print(x)
```

From my understanding, this code will iterate through the elements in that txt file like so:

```
Dave
Jack
Mary
```

However, when I try something like this:

```
with open('Hi.txt','r') as hello:
    x = hello.read()
    for i,v in enumerate(x,1):
        print(i,v)
```

It prints out every character one by one.

Desired output:

```
1 Dave
2 Jack
3 Mary
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You enumerate the file handle itself:

```
with open('/Hi.txt','r') as hello:
    for i,v in enumerate(hello,1):
        print(i,v, end="")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
with open('Hi.txt','r') as hello:
    for i,v in enumerate(hello.readlines(), 1):
        print(i,v, end="")
```

This will iterate for all the lines in your file (*assuming you have all the file items in separated lines*).

Comment: i think it should be `for i,v in enumerate(hello)` not `hello.readlines()`

Comment: There are two ways in which this doesn't give the OP what he/she wants. - this basically works, but you've missed two details that mean it isn't quite right.

Comment: @JoeFerndz I just tested and it is exactly the same using `enumerate(hello)` and `enumerate(hello.readlines())`

Comment: @Steve what did i miss? The end of line?

Comment: yeah...and your index values start at 0, not 1

Comment: Ohh i see...starting at one...is that isn't it?

Comment: Yeah @Steve you where right, didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: @JorgeMorgado, I see that you are doing readlines() so it gets everything into the range. And you are using v to do the default \n forcing end = "". Nice. Upvoted for ingenuity

Comment: @JoeFerndz yeah is basically the same answer that Steve wrote :)